# inequality about finite sums

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

This is a problem from Selected Problems in Analysis, Makarov, B. M. et al.

> Suppose $(a_n:n=1,\ldots,n)$ is a sequence of real numbers. For any $0\leq m\leq n$, define
> $$\widetilde{S}_m=\sum^m_{k=1}a_k -\sum^n_{j=m+1}a_j$$
> with the understanding that $\widetilde{S}_0=-\sum^n_{j=1}a_j=-\widetilde{S}_n$.
> The problem is to show that there is $0\leq m\leq n$ such that $|\widetilde{S}_m|\leq \max_{1\leq j\leq n}|a_j|$,

So far the best I get is $|\widetilde{S}_m|\leq 2\max_{1\leq j\leq n}|a_j|$. To get this, I notice that as $\widetilde{S}_0=-\sum^n_{j=1}a_j=-\widetilde{S}_n$, the sequence $(\widetilde{S}_j:1\leq j\leq n)$ changes sign (or all terms $a_j$ are zero and the problem becomes trivial). Without loss of generality, assume that $p$ is the smallest integer in $\{0,\ldots,n\}$ for which $\widetilde{S}_{p-1}<0<\widetilde{S}_p$.
Then, $\widetilde{S}_p=\widetilde{S}_{p-1}+2a_p>0$. This implies that $a_p>0$ and
$\widetilde{S}_p<2a_p$, and $|\widetilde{S}_{p-1}|\leq 2a_p$.
I can't seem to get a better estimate at the moment.

Any useful hint and/or a solution will be appreciated.

Comment: $|S_{p}|+|S_{p-1}|=S_p-S_{p-1}=2a_p$. So $\min(|S_p|,|S_{p-1}|)\le a_p$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: Oh dear! that is embarrassingly simple. I just could not see past what I had. Thank you!